# Android Graphical Layout unable to render with v7 support widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, graphical-layout-editor, switchcompat

The graphical layout is unable to render because of a v7 support widget within my layout XML. I am using the following support widget:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/view_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

The error that I'm getting is: 
`Failed to find style 'windowFixedWidthMajor' in current theme java.lang.NullPointerException`
Which is only logical cause the style is defined in the v7 support library.

Does anybody now how to fix this issue?

Comment: This seems to be a general problem with the Android Studio preview window. Anything that comes from a library, it has difficulty rendering.

Comment: Still happening with AS version 1.5.1.  I have little hope that these problems will ever be addressed.